# Dual quaternion Implementation in C

Tags: c

I have read about dual quaternions and their properties, but do not know how I can implement it using C . I mean basic operations such as multiplication, addition, conjugate, inverse, norm, etc. but using C language.

My intention is to use the dual quaternion skinning for my mesh.

Hopefully someone can help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your question.  A quaternion basically functions like a 4 element object where one element is a scaler and the other three elements form a vector.  Dual quaternions is taken to mean that you have two of them.  The exact transform for a quaternion is probably listed in Wickipedia.  In C you will need to create a structure that has 4 "double" variables and then code methods to perform the two operand operations of: add/sub/mult/div (again Wickipedia).  It is easily doable in C and would be a fun project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dual quaternion library in C with source you can use or study.

[libdq](https://github.com/bobbens/libdq)